# How to reference another property type of the current interface when defining interface/types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let say i have this custom Interface that extends the Response type in javascript. What i'm trying to achieve is creating conditional types of the `json()` method return type based on its `status` property value.

```js
interface ApiResponse<
  Expected = unknown,
  ValidationErrors extends string[] | unknown = unknown,
> extends Response {
  status: Response['status'];
  json: () => Response['status'] extends 422
    ? Promise<
        ValidationErrors extends string[]
          ? ValidationErrorResponse<ValidationErrors>
          : Response
      >
    : Response['status'] extends Exclude<IntRange<400, 599>, 422>
    ? Promise<ErrorResponse>
    : Promise<
        Expected extends object
          ? ResourceResponse<Expected>
          : Response
      >;
}}
```

So then when i'm using custom fetch function that will return this ApiResponse promise, i can use it like this:

```js
async function run() {
  const data = await vetch<{ token: string }, ['email','password']>('');
  const json = await data.json();
  if (data.status === 200) {
    const res = json; // ResourceResponse<Expected>
  } else if (data.status === 422) {
    const res = json; // ValidationErrorResponse<ValidationErrors>
  } else {
    const res = json; // ErrorResponse
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs, without unrelated issue like undeclared types or values, typos, etc.